# Sveltekit Base URL for subdirectory throws 404

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I need a bit of understanding for serving a Sveltekit app from a subdirectory. My company will serve the app from a subdirectory called `/activ`. I figure it's easy enough to update the appropriate paths like so:

**svelte.config.js:**

```
kit: {
  ...
  paths: {
    base: "/activ"
  },
  adapter: adapter({
    fallback: 'index.html' // render as SPA
  }),
}
```

**routes/index.svelte:**

```
<svelte:head>
  <base href="/activ">
</svelte:head>
```

When I `npm run build` and copy the build over to the subdirectory on the server, the app loads and functions as expected.

However, when I try to serve from dev (localhost:3000) I receive the following errors:

**http://localhost:3000**

```
Not Found
```

**http://localhost:3000/activ** (what would be the subdirectory and Base URL)

```
404
Not found: 
Error: Not found: 
    at resolve (file:///Users/tomdoe/Sites/__playground/sveltekit-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/ssr.js:1728:13)
    at async respond (file:///Users/tomdoe/Sites/__playground/sveltekit-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/ssr.js:1676:10)
    at async Immediate.<anonymous> (file:///Users/tomdoe/Sites/__playground/sveltekit-app/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/dist/chunks/index.js:3484:22)
```

It seems that I don't understand how to mimic the subdirectory when serving from dev (localhost). Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
rel="external"
```

Read following.

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options#data-sveltekit-reload

Comment: this link is expired. Do you have a new one?

Comment: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/link-options#data-sveltekit-reload